# A reduce function (for many set unions) in C++

Tags: c++, stl, set, reduce

**What I am trying to do:**
I have a simple set union function in C++ using STL, and I'm trying to wrap it in a function that will let me perform the union of arbitrarily many sets contained in STL data structures (e.g. `std::list`, `std::vector`, `std::forward_list`, ...).

**How I tried to do it:**
To start, my simple set union:

```
#include <algorithm>
template <typename set_type>
set_type sunion(const set_type & lhs, const set_type & rhs)
{
  set_type result;
  std::set_union( lhs.begin(), lhs.end(), rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), std::inserter(result, result.end()) );
  return result;
}
```

where `set_type` defines some STL `std::set<T>`, e.g. `std::set<int>`.

After noticing several times that I end up needing to perform several unions on iterators of sets (in `Python` this would be a `reduce` of my `sunion` function over some iterable object of `set_type`s). For instance, I might have

```
std::vector<std::set<int> > all_sets;
```

or

```
std::list<std::set<int> > all_sets;
```

etc., and I want to get the union of all sets in `all_sets`. I am trying to implement a simple reduce for this, which essentially does a (faster, more elegant, non-copying) version of:

```
sunion(... sunion( sunion( all_sets.begin(), all_sets.begin()+1 ), all_sets.begin()+2 ) , ... )
```

Essentially, to do this quickly, I just want to declare a `set_type result` and then iterate through `all_sets` and insert value in every set in `all_sets` into the result object:

```
template <typename set_type>
set_type sunion_over_iterator_range(const std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, set_type> & begin, const std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, set_type> & end)
{
  set_type result;
  for (std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, set_type> iter = begin; iter != end; iter++)
    {
      insert_all(result, *iter);
    }
  return result;
}
```

where `insert_all` is defined:

```
// |= operator; faster than making a copy and performing union
template <typename set_type>
void insert_all(set_type & lhs, const set_type & rhs)
{
  for (typename set_type::iterator iter = rhs.begin(); iter != rhs.end(); iter++)
    {
      lhs.insert(*iter);
    }
}
```

**How it didn't work:**
Unfortunately, my `sunion_over_iterator_range(...)` doesn't work with arguments `std::vector<set_type>::begin(), std::vector<set_type>::end()`, which are of type `std::vector<set_type>::iterator`. I thought `std::vector<T>::iterator` returns an `iterator<random_access_iterator_tag, T>`. A

After compilation failed because of type incompatibility of the iterators, I looked at the stl vector source (located in **/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_vector.h** for g++ 4.6 & Ubuntu 11.10), and was surprised to see the typedef for `vector<T>::iterator` to be `typedef __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<pointer, vector> iterator;`. I had thought that a [ForwardIterator was a subtype of RandomAccessIterator, and so should be fine](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/ForwardIterator/), but clearly I was incorrect, or I would not be here.

**How I am grateful and ashamed of inciting your frustration due to my inexperience:**
Apologies if I'm showing my ignorance-- I am trying to learn to be a better object oriented programmer (in the past I have simply hacked everything out in C-style code).

I'm doing my best, coach! Please help me out and spare the world from bad code that I would produce without your code ninja insight...

Comment: C++ has an equivalent of Python's `reduce`. It is called [std::accumulate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate). (I'm not sure if it helps in this situation though).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, when using iterators we don't care about the actual category. Just let the implementation sort it out. That means, just change the function to accept any type:

```
template <typename T>
typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type sunion_over_iterator_range(T begin, T end)
{
   typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type result;
   for (T iter = begin; iter != end; ++ iter)
   {
      insert_all(result, *iter);
   }
   return result;
}
```

Note that I have used [`typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits), which is the type of `*iter`.

BTW, the iterator pattern is not related to OOP. (That doesn't mean it's a bad thing).

Comment: +1 This is essentially what I want to do. Is there some way for the return value to be of `set_type` rather than an iterator? With that, it's exactly what I want.

Comment: Ah-- never mind, somehow the compiler figured out the right type of template arguments. But regardless, I would love to see an explanation of `std::iterator_traits` (I'll check the link)-- it seems to be the inverse of `iterable_type::iterator`, going from an iterator to some type containing it. The other answers were extremely complete and very useful, but this is closest to what I had in mind (after all, it wasn't the algorithm that was tricky, just allowing the right argument types).

Answer (score 9):

Here's a very naive approach:

```
std::set<T> result;
std::vector<std::set<T>> all_sets;

for (std::set<T> & s : all_sets)
{
    result.insert(std::make_move_iterator(s.begin()),
                  std::make_move_iterator(s.end()));
}
```

This invalidates the elements in the source sets, though it doesn't actually move the element nodes over. If you want to leave the source sets intact, just remove the `make_move_iterator`.

Unfortunately there's no interface for `std::set` that lets you "splice" two sets in a way that doesn't reallocate the internal tree nodes, so this is more or less as good as you can get.

Here's a variadic template approach:

```
template <typename RSet> void union(RSet &) { }

template <typename RSet, typename ASet, typename ...Rest>
void union(RSet & result, ASet const & a, Rest const &... r)
{
    a.insert(a.begin(), a.end());
    union(result, r...);
}
```

Usage:

```
std::set<T> result
union(result, s1, s2, s3, s4);
```

(Similar move-optimizations are feasible here; you can even add some branching that will copy from immutables but move from mutables, or from rvalues only, if you like.)

Here's a version using `std::accumulate`:

```
std::set<T> result =
   std::accumulate(all_sets.begin(), all_sets.end(), std::set<T>(),
                   [](std::set<T> & s, std::set<T> const & t)
                     { s.insert(t.begin(), t.end()); return s; }    );
```

This version seems to rely on return value optimisation a lot, though, so you might like to compare it to this hacked up and rather ugly version:

```
std::set<T> result;
std::accumulate(all_sets.begin(), all_sets.end(), 0,
                [&result](int, std::set<T> const & t)
                { result.insert(t.begin(), t.end()); return 0; } );
```

Comment: This is nitpicky, but you'll have to separate the `> >` characters in `<std::set<T>>` so that you have `<std::set<T> >`. If you put them right after each other, C++ interprets it as a right shift token, which is not what you want.

Comment: @Datalore: Then you should also nitpick the `for(T& s : ss)` syntax :)

Comment: Huge +1 for showing me `for(T& s : ss)` for the first time! ^_^

Comment: i knew there had to be something like accumulate in the std but i had no idea what they called it.